# Navigationbar is shown and but its not placed correctly in iphone

Tags: iphone

When i call this method, the navigationbar is shown and its not placed correctly. Exactly navigation bar placed from 20pixels from top of simulator. How to solve this. I call this method before subclass. but next page navigation bar not placed correctly.

```
UtilityController *object=[[UtilityController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UtilityController" bundle:nil];
navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:object];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
[object release];
```

How to solve this method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you hide the status bar at the top? :)

Comment: why are you adding subview? you can present it using `[self presentModalViewController:navigationController];` Try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set appropriate value of `frame` property of your `navigationController`, for exmaple:

```
navigationController.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

Also the best practice is to set `UINavigationController` as modal view:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

**New example**

```
UtilityController *object=[[UtilityController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UtilityController"    bundle:nil];
navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:object];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[object release];
[navigationController release];
```

Comment: how to call this method with above the code. can u give the code pls

Comment: UtilityController *object=[[UtilityController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UtilityController" bundle:nil];

[navigationController.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) initWithRootViewController:object]; 
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
 [object release]; 
is this code is right?

Comment: if it works then accept and upvote the answer, so that others may take help from it. :)